# How to use enriched queries for an element of an array into nested structs Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to search for a value into an array of nested structs. For example:

chaincode.go

```
//My structs
type Maininfo struct {
    ObjectType          string     `json:"docType"`
    Name                string     `json:"name"`
    Concept             MyConcept `json:"concept"`
}

type MyConcept struct {
    Keys []string `json:"keys"`
    Value    int   `json:"value"`
}


func (c *Sample) queryByKey(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response {
    if len(args) != 1 {
        return shim.Error("Invalid Argument Number. Expected 1")
    }

    key := args[0]
//Myquerystring
   queryString := fmt.Sprintf("{\"selector\":{\"docType\":\"MyObject\", \"concept.keys\":{\"$elemMatch\":{\"%s\"}}}", key)
```

the ouput is:

---

SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()

---

Comment: The problem is with  `\"concept.keys\" `, don't use `.` notation use Object notation.

Comment: @Aditya Joshi thank you for your response. Could you give me an example for a case like this?

Comment: what is your requirement, according to that I will create a chaincode on my local environment and run that and will share the snippet?

Comment: Meanwhile try to print the response with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @Aditya Joshi I want to PutState my structs like below with key the field "Name" and i want to create enriched query base on the field "keys" which is an array on nested structs. For example the keys fields is ["apple", "banana"] and i want to query the json object if the array has the "apple".